# Symfony trying to use an array of id in set parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use an array of ids in a setParameter
Here my fingeringId array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 665930
    [1] => 666021
    [2] => 666152
    [3] => 666454
    [4] => 666562
    [5] => 666732
    [6] => 666971
    [7] => 667359
    [8] => 667817
    [9] => 668182
    [10] => 668296
    [11] => 668519
)
```

Here my query_builder

```
->add('fingering', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ManagerBundle\Entity\Fingering',
                    'property' => 'fingerings',
                    'query_builder' => function($er) use ($fingeringIds) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                            ->select('f')
                            ->where('f.id = :ids')
                            ->setParameter('ids', array_values($fingeringIds));
                    },
                    'expanded' => true,
                ))
```

I get an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 666021, 666152, 666454, 666562, 666732, 666971, 667359, 667817, 668182, 668296,' at line 1
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `IN`:

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                        ->select('f')
                        ->where('f.id IN (:ids)')
                        ->setParameter('ids', array_values($fingeringIds));
```